# Как настроить apache2 так, чтоб виртуальные хосты были видны в локальной сети?

Tags: ubuntu, apache, localhost

Друзья, вынужден признаться, что туповат в современных технологиях. И часто не понимаю, что мне нужно прочитать, чтоб понять, что мне нужно сделать. Читать умею и люблю, так что если вы просто дадите мне ссылки на подходящее чтиво - буду очень благодарен.

Заранее предупреждаю, что вопрос ставлю не вполне корректно, т.к. google мне не может на него ответить. Возможно, я что-то принципиально неверно понимаю.

**Дано:**

1. ubuntu 14.04
2. Apache 2.4.7
3. Все настроено и работает. Т.е. на этом же компе я могу по придуманному адресу обратиться к сайту.
4. Все компы подключены к сети через Wi-Fi-роутер, который подключен к интернет.
5. файл hosts выглядит так:

> ```
> # Это доменные адреса, соответствующие локальному ip?
> 127.0.0.1 localhost 
> 127.0.0.1 blog.loc 
> 127.0.0.1 yii2.loc 
> 127.0.0.1 symfony.loc 
> 127.0.0.1 laravel.loc         
>
> # Это локальный ip-адрес моего компьютера? Чем он отличается от предыдущего? 
> 127.0.1.1 zzwan
>
> # Абракадабру ниже я не понимаю вообще
> ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
> fe00::0 ip6-localnet
> ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
> ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
> ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
> ```

**Задача:** настроить локальный сервер так, чтоб во всей локальной сети были видны сайты по указанным выше адресам.

Comment: так надо конфиг апача приводить, а не ваш hosts, он здесь вообще не при делах. А в конфиге апача надо указывать не 127.0.0.1, а внешний ip, т.е. ip, по которому можно достучаться до этого сервака с другого компа

Comment: Какие настройки apache интересуют? Как они называются? У меня единственное, что там написано похожего - это ```ServerName localhost``` ip-адрес там вообще не фигурирует.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Вашем понимании задачи есть одна очень существенная ошибка. А именно, Вы считаете, что настраивать нужно локальный сервер. Но настраивать для этого локальный сервер совершенно не нужно. Дело в том, что обращение к сайту по имени происходит в следующей последовательности:

- браузер получает запрос на открытие сайта `site-name.domain`;
- служба DNS пытается разрешить имя `site-name.domain` в IP-адрес;
- браузер устанавливает соединение с сервером, IP-адрес которого он получил на предыдущем шаге;
- браузер посылает по соединению запрос, в котором просит сервер выдать ему страницу с именем `site-name.domain`.

Чтобы обращаться к сайту по имени, как видно из вышесказанного, нужно чтобы браузер смог правильно разрешить имя `site-name.domain` в IP-адрес. Для этого используется DNS. DNS может выдать адрес либо из локального файла `hosts`, где адрес прописывается администратором, либо же получить его с DNS-сервера, обслуживающего требуемую зону.

Вряд ли Ваш Wi-Fi роутер умеет работать авторитативным DNS-сервером для зоны, поэтому в Вашем случае проще всего на каждом компьютере вашей сети (надеюсь, их не много) прописать в файле hosts для каждого вашего домена записи вида

```
1.2.3.4 site-name.domain
```

Здесь `1.2.3.4` нужно будет заменить на адрес вашего компьютера в локальной сети. (Следует иметь в виду, что адресам от `127.0.0.1` до `127.255.255.255`, т.е. подсети `127.0.0.0/8` всегда соответствует **локальный** компьютер.)

В качестве второго варианта решения задачи можно использовать собственный DNS-сервер, расположенный на отдельном компьютере, обслуживающий требуемую Вам зону.

Comment: спасибо. Чуть просветлело. Когда получится - дополню ответ тем, что я сделал и приму.

Comment: т.е., как я понял, мне нужно настроить свой DNS-сервер. Верно?

Comment: @Razzwan Либо настроить свой DNS-сервер, либо вписать все домены в `hosts` на каждой машине.

Comment: Да, спасибо, только что попробовал это сделать и получилось ) правда, не знаю, как это сделать на android, но думаю нагуглю. Спасибо.

Comment: @Razzwan К сожалению, нерутованный Android поменять `hosts` не даст...