# Не могу получить доступ к серверу teamcity в локальной сети

Tags: сеть, teamcity

У нас есть сервер *TeamCity* на *Mac*, имеющий статический IP. Мы настроили *NAT* для доступа к этому компьютеру через порт *8111* (порт тимсити).

Это значит, что у нас есть общий *IP* адрес, под которым мы выходим в www. И любой компьютер, который обращается по этому *IP:8111* будет переведен на Mac в локальной сети.

Так вот если мы заходим в веб-интерфейс *TeamCity* по этому *IP* с внешней машины, то всё хорошо.
А если мы задим из под машины в локальной сети, то получаем ошибку

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: обращайтесь по локальному ip-адресу.

Comment: В нашем чате есть канал *TeamCity*, в котором бот публикует ссылки с тем самым публичным *IP*. Если заменить его на локальный, то ссылки смогут окрыть только те, кто сейчас в локальной сети.

Comment: в ссылках фигурирует имя или ip-адрес? если имя, то настройте свой nameserver так, чтобы он внутри сети резолвил это имя в локальный ip-адрес. или пропишите нужное соответствие в `/etc/hosts` (в операционных системах от *ms* этот файл где-то в каталоге `windows` или как-то в этом духе).

Comment: ответы примерно на эту тему: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/467685/178576 и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431598/178576

Comment: В моем случае фигурирует сам ip адрес, он определен настройками роутера. Я так понял из ваших ответов, что DNS преобразует буквенное наименование в IP адрес, но не позволяет преобразовать (перенаправить) имеющийся IP в другой.

Comment: *не позволяет преобразовать (перенаправить) имеющийся IP в другой* — к dns это не имеет отношения. так может сделать, например, маршрутизатор. *фигурирует сам ip адрес* — **внешний** ip-адрес? настройте ваш маршрутизатор так, чтобы он делал **правильное** перенаправление. если не знаете как, обратитесь к специалистам.